# "object 'i' not found" the for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to make a simple for loop, that would add a new column to the existing data frame, by assigning a time class to each observation. I am getting 'object 'i' not found' and not sure where is a mistake. I am not that experienced with R, so thank you for any help!

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(my.data)) {
    if(my.data$RTime[i] <= 3600){
        my.data$RTimeHour[i] <- 1
    }ifelse (my.data$RTime[i] > 3601 & my.data$RTime[i] < 7200){
        my.data$RTimeHour[i] <- 2
    }esle {
        my.data$RTimeHour[i] <- 3
    }
}
```

Comment: You have at least one typo. The last one should be `else`. Also you probably want `else if` rather that `ifelse`

Comment: Also, you should use the vectorized `ifelse()` or `dplyr::case_when()`. That will be much more performant than row wise iteration over a data frame and is less prone to errors than such a verbose for-loop

Comment: Another type is `> 3601`: if the value **is** 3601, it will get value `3` in `my.data$RTimeHour` while it **should** get `2`.

Comment: type --> typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use a nested `ifelse` statement:

```
my.data$RTimeHour <- ifelse(my.data$RTime <= 3600, 1,
                            ifelse(my.data$RTime > 3600 & my.data$RTime <= 7200, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably coming from the ifelse() you have:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(my.data)) {
    if(my.data$RTime[i] <= 3600){
        my.data$RTimeHour[i] <- 1
    }ifelse (my.data$RTime[i] > 3601 & my.data$RTime[i] < 7200){
        my.data$RTimeHour[i] <- 2
    }esle {
        my.data$RTimeHour[i] <- 3
    }
}
```

Try this instead:

```
    if(my.data$RTime[i] <= 3600){
        my.data$RTimeHour[i] <- 1
    }else if(my.data$RTime[i] > 3601 & my.data$RTime[i] < 7200){
        my.data$RTimeHour[i] <- 2
    }else {
        my.data$RTimeHour[i] <- 3
    }
}

ifelse vectorizes how the problem, so ifelse(x[i]) will try to refer to something outside of the loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

Vectorized with `tidyverse` we can just do:

```
library(tidyverse)

my.data %>% mutate(RTimeHour = case_when(
    RTime <= 3600 ~ 1,
    RTime < 7200 ~ 2,
    TRUE ~ 3)
)
```